# Javascript .getJSON .each only works some of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running into an interesting issue that I cannot figure out. I am dynamically loading some data into an html `<select></select>`.

What I am discovering is that as I refresh the page, sometimes the data loads, but more often than not, there is nothing there. Is the page loading too quickly or the file not getting processed every time the page reloads?

I have tried multiple browsers and the experience is the same.

Here is my html:

```
<select id="group-select-user-access" class="blue-text">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Google Group</option>
</select>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var group_list = "json/google_group_list.json";

        $.getJSON(group_list, function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key) {
                var email_stripped = json[key].substring(0, json[key].lastIndexOf("@"));
                $('select[id=group-select-user-access]').append('<option value="' + email_stripped + '">' + json[key] + '</option>');
            });
        });
</script>
```

The .json file is simple and in this format:

```
["email1@test.com", "email2@test.com", "email3@test.com", ...]
```

I am relatively new when it comes to JS / jQuery so any help is appreciated.

What direction should I head next for troubleshooting?

Comment: Anytime I see the words "only works some of the time" I can be sure the problem is a race condition without even reading another word. You might need to wrap the $.getJSON call with a document.ready. It's possible it's running before the DOM exists. I can't remember if jQuery protects you from that or not. So the race condition is that sometimes your dom renders first, and sometimes the javascript runs first.

Comment: Well you've over complicated your selector this `$('select[id=group-select-user-access]')` would be better expressed as `$("#group-select-user-access") but @mkaatman is right you have some type of race condition going on. Can you provide any other info about what else is going on?

Comment: Probably the DOM hasn't loaded all of the time. Wrap the process in document ready

Comment: Move your script tag to the end of the document.

Comment: Hmm ok I tried the `$(document).ready(function() {}` with no avail, that did not work 100% of the time. The script tag that this code is located in is already at the end of the document. Very strange to say the least. Not quite sure about the down vote, if more information is needed I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: I have the page open in Safari and in Chrome. Currently, when I reload Chrome it works but not in Safari. Could it be some sort of caching issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with the DOM not being fully loaded when you try to modify it

Try either moving your script tag to the very end of your document, or wrap your js code with `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var group_list = "json/google_group_list.json";

        $.getJSON(group_list, function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key) {
                var email_stripped = json[key].substring(0, json[key].lastIndexOf("@"));
                $('select[id=group-select-user-access]').append('<option value="' + email_stripped + '">' + json[key] + '</option>');
            });
        });
    })
```

That way your code will wait until the entire document is loaded before trying to append things to it